# Making all the values in a file convertible to float

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, casting

I want to make all the values in a file to be typecasted into *float*. I am taking in the file *101.txt* and writing the typecast-able values into another file *n101.txt*.

My code :

```
f2 = open('n101.txt', 'w+')
with open("101.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        for i in line.split(' '):
            try:
                float(i)
            except ValueError:
                pass
            else:
                f2.write(i + " ")
        f2.write("\n")
```

When I check the file (using similar code as above, without try except), I still get to see values that are not convertible to float. How does this happen ?

Comment: What gets converted to `float` even if it shouldn't?

Comment: Probably additional spaces and empty characters which I am not aware of

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
f2 = open('n101.txt', 'w+')
with open("101.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        for i in line.split(' '):
            try:
                i = float(i)
            except ValueError:
                pass
            else:
                f2.write(str(i) + " ")
        f2.write("\n")
f2.close()
```

The line `float(i)` doesn't do anything itself. Actually it returns float value of `i`, but doesn't change `i` itself.

Above program works as below:

```
#101.txt
1
2
3
```

Output:

```
#n101.txt
1.0
2.0
3.0
```

Comment: The `with` statement closes automatically file `f`, there's no need for `f.close()`.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu Thanks you for mentioning it. Answer edited.